# Exiting command from python script whilst continuing to run script

Tags: python, linux, command

I'm trying to automate the process of sending deAuth packets to a network using Kali Linux and monitor mode. For the command

```
airodump-ng <interface name>
```

There are listed nearby networks which are constantly updated in the terminal window. To run the next command (normally) the user needs to use `Ctrl + C` or `Ctrl + Z` to exit the command and run the next one.

So far I have been able to run all necessary commands from within a python script using `subprocess.call()` (and `raw_input()` where necessary), however exiting the `airodump-ng` function causes this to exit the script as well.

Is it possible to exit the previous command's running output without exiting the python script i.e. a command that can be used via `subprocess.call()`? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.kill()`?

Comment: @moritzg Yeah and no suck luck. I use `time.sleep()` to wait for the output to populate and then use `dump.kill()` and the output continues to print

Answer (score 0):

you can make your command run in the background using `nohup` command and keep the script running in the background while you stay in the same terminal,however,you can't access the results from that script however the you can use use `cat nohup.out` to see the results of the script

you can proceed as follow

```
nohup python scriptname.py &
```

This will keep your script running in the background and dumping the results of the scripts in a file in the same folder where you ve run the command called `nohup.out`

After that to check the result of the execution of your script
do

```
cat nohup.out
```

to see all results of the scripts
or

```
tail nohup.out
```

to check the last 10 lines of the your script.

The advantage for this is that you will stay in the same terminal prompt and will be able to execute

```
airodump-ng <interface name>
```

note that you can also do

```
 airodump-ng <interface name> &
```

if you want it to be runnning  in the background

or

```
nohup airodump-ng <interface name> &
```

if you want the results to be dumped in nohup.out file that will be created after running this command in your current working folder.